# How to multiply 3X1 matrix with 1X3 matrix using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to multiply [[3],[1],[0]] with matrix [1,-1,3] using numpy. But it is not able to perform that.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[3],[1],[0]])
b = np.array([1,-1,3])

x = np.dot(a,b)
print(x)
```

it is returning error as " ValueError: shapes (3,1) and (3,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0) "

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html

Comment: a = np.array([3,1,0])

Comment: `dot` seeks to pair the last dimension of `a` with the 2nd to the last (or only) dimension of `b`.  That's why it's complaining that 1 is not equal to 3.  With `dot(b,a)` the 3's pair.  `np.dot` docs tries to explain this.

Comment: `a * b` works, producing a (3,3) 'outer' product.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your shape is not right (shape of b is `(3,)`, it needs to be `(1,3)`) .

```py
a = np.array([[3],[1],[0]])
b = np.array([[1,-1,3]])  #Make it 2D list to have shape (1, 3)
np.dot(a,b)

array([[ 3, -3,  9],
       [ 1, -1,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write b also as a matrix:

```
b = np.array([[1,-1,3]])
```

Comment: Thanks. so much, it is working now, However, with the same previous shape i could perform b dot a.